# Thatwe SSL123 Installation issue on CPanel, Invalid Certificate on Firefox

Tags: security-certificate, cpanel

I have tried to install digital certificate on the CPanel, Everything giving success

I have purchased and installed one Thawte SSL123 Certificate for domin dev.znda.net on Cpanel.Everything works fine in Google chrome.. But in Firefox it gives "Invalid Certificate"

I am getting this error after verification from thawte verification website...

https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO9555

```
dev.znda.net failed for the following reasons: 
The intermediate CA certificates cannot be found for the following certificate chain.
```

Answer (score 2):

To get these certificates to work, you must install more than just the certificate itself, you must properly install an entire certificate chain.

The proper chain of intermediate certificates can be downloaded from https://community.thawte.com/forums/downloading-intermediate-ca-bundle-ssl123 where they also have instructions for installing them under cpanel: https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO15567